# MongoDB C# - Update vs FindOne with [-1]

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a property class:

```
class
{
    string Key;
    string Value;
}
```

and I have an object like this:

```
{
    ....
    List<Property> Properties
}
```

If I want to add a property, I can do this:

```
Filter: _ => _.id == MyId && _.Properties.Any(__ => __.Key == MyKey)
Update: AddToSet(_ => _.Properties, new Property { Key = MyKey, Value = MyValue })
```

And if I want to edit an existing property, I can do this:

```
Filter: _ => _.id == MyId && _.Properties.Any(__ => __.Key == MyKey)
Update: Set(_ => _.Properties[-1].Value, MyValue)
```

And this works well. (As a secondary question: can I do some kind of upsert in this scenario where a property is either created or replaced?)

The problem comes from getting the data back:

```
Query: _ => _._id == MyId && _.Properties.Any(__ => __.Key == MyKey))
```

This will return the object *if* it has the right key, but the projection will fail:

```
Query: _ => _._id == MyId && _.Properties.Any(__ => __.Key == MyKey))
Projection: Expression(_ => _.Properties[-1].Value)
```

This will return null.. Is *[-1]* not working with projections?

I can get it to work like this:

```
Projection: Expression(_ => _.Properties.First(__ => __.Key == Name).Value)
```

but this doesn't explain why [-1] is not working.

Comment: not answering your question, but I have to comment your example: using an underscore when naming lambda params is a convention for when *not* using a parameter. this hurts my eyes

Comment: To me, it makes it more readable as it brings more space; I'm involved in a discussion on this topic on the C# repo: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1064. One option would be to keep '_' only for the discard operator and use @ to reference the object instead; for example: @.Properties in this context